# Selenium Webdriver failed when use window_handles

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-7

I am trying to handle Two Tab in Python Selenium webdriver with Chrome as browser.

I am getting result for find element by link text on first tab as well as second tab if I keep the **Chrome Browser as selected window**.[i.e Front Screen Process ]

When I change the control to new tab using

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

and minimise the google chrome[i.e if I select any process other than Google Chrome].i get the error in finding the link text saying **Element Not Found Exception** for Second Tab only not on first Tab.

I am getting result on First Tab.

```
def DriverCreation():
    try:
        Driver = WebBase.initWebScraping(URL)   # Methods visible Driver.driver and Driver.loggerDriverWait = Driver.EC
        print "Driver Creation Successful"
        return Driver
    except:
        print "Driver Initalisation Failed"
        sys.exit(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    URL = 'https://www.example.com/'
    Driver = DriverCreation() # will Load first Tab with www.Example.com
    aboutlink = Driver.driver.find_element_by_link_text('about')
    aboutlink.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
    Driver.driver.switch_to_window(Driver.driver.window_handles[1])
    contactLink =  Driver.driver.find_element_by_link_text('contact')
    print contactLink.text()  #** getting error if i change the focus from Google Chrome and works fine if i keep the window focus on Google Chrome**
```

Comment: can you put some extra code so we can understand your problem easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manage tab using following code.

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"', '_blank');")
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: when i change the focus from Google Chrome will script run ?

Comment: you need to put URL which one you open new tab.

Comment: it worked. After itterating a 800 records memory size of chrome is increasing a lot, almost 3gb

Comment: you can quit and restore chrome after some request otherwise you have to manage memory size